# A question about Abel's test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Abel's test for $\sum a_n b_n$ to converge requires:
>
> 1. $\sum a_n$ converges
> 2. ${b_n}$ is bounded
> 3. ${b_n}$ is monotone.

My question is why do we need the 3d condition?

The 2nd condition implies that there exists $M>0: |b_n| < M$. Then $\sum a_n b_n \leq M \sum a_n$, where the latter series converges, hence $\sum a_n b_n$ converges. What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_n = (-1)^n / n$, $b_n = (-1)^n$. Then $\{b_n\}$ is bounded and not monotone, while $\sum_n a_n$ converges (it's an alternating series). However, $$\sum_n a_n b_n = \sum_n \frac 1 n$$

is the divergent harmonic series.

---

It looks like you're assuming some notion of *absolute* convergence in $\sum a_n$, which is much more than Abel's test requires. The problem is that

$$a_n b_n \le a_n M$$

would be true if $a_n$ were always positive; but this isn't true in general.

Comment: i.e. "monotone $b_n$" can be replaced with "$a_n \geq 0$". Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Well, *yes*, but it's not very useful. In that case, $\sum a_n$ is already an absolutely convergent series, which is a very powerful piece of information. The test is a bit useless then.

Comment: You're very welcome.